# How do I delete my account and all questions/answers on IPS, but keep it on all other SE sites?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I want to delete my account and all my questions/answers/activity on IPS, but keep my account open on all other Stack Exchange sites.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can delete your profile, but all the rest of your activity remains. You are not allowed (Except in certain circumstances) to delete your activity: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13976/who-owns-the-copyright-to-sofu-content.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can go to your profile, and click "Edit", which should take you to this page: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current

When you're there, on the left, you'll see this:

[image]

Click "delete profile".

You'll get this page (at https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/delete/current):

[image]

Check the checkbox, and click "delete profile".

The account will then go into a queue for the staff to review and approve the deletion.

---

For legal issues on Stack Exchange, you can contact them [here](https://stackexchange.com/legal/contact)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80098/discussion-on-answer-by-arwen-undomiel-how-do-i-delete-my-account-and-all-questi).